# Getting current time of different timezone by providing timezone value

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pytz

In a scenario where I don't know the name of the time zone area, I need to get the current time in a specific `timezone`. Basically, I need a method where I will pass the `UTC` value of timezone and expect the return as the current time of the area.
the method which I need should be like`

```
def get_current_time(utc_value):
    #CODE
    return current_time
print (get_current_time("+05:30"))`
```

And I expect it should give me the current time of `UTC` +5:30 timezone.
How to do it?

Comment: @iam.Carrot, I wanted to pass the UTC in a string and get the time of that zone, I have cope up with a solution too, but if there is any other way also, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pytz import all_timezones, timezone
from datetime import datetime

def get_cuurent_time(utc_value):
    for zone in all_timezones:
        tz = timezone(zone)
        if utc_value in  str(datetime.now(tz)):
            return datetime.now(tz)
print (get_cuurent_time("+05:30"))
```

I made it, bother not :),  but if there is any other way also, please let me know.